# How to write my CMakeLists.txt for this unusual header structure?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to write a `CMakeLists.txt` for my project in C++, that depends on a few third party libraries. One of the libraries follows an unusual pattern (to me) when including header files as described below.

My code is structured as:

```
project/
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - src/
    - main.cpp
  - lib/
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - moduleA/
        -CMakeLists.txt
        - fooA.cpp
        - fooA.h
        - barA.cpp
        - barA.h
    - moduleB/
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - fooB.cpp
        - fooB.h
```

`moduleA` depends on `moduleB`, and in addition `fooA` also depends on `barA`. The issue is with the `include` statements of `fooA.cpp` and `barA.cpp`:

```cpp
// fooA.cpp
#include "moduleA/fooA.h"
#include "moduleA/barA.h"
...
```

Likewise for `barA.cpp`. When I run `make` after `cmake` it complains that it cannot find `moduleA/fooA.h` while compiling `fooA.cpp`. I am not sure how to include the files in `moduleA`, or in which `CMakeLists.txt` should I include those. `moduleB` compiles properly. I cannot change the code of the libraries, but I can add `cmake` files.

My `CMakeLists.txt` in `lib` and `CMakeLists.txt` in `moduleA` are as follows.

```
# lib/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.14)
project(mylibs VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_subdirectory(moduleA)
add_subdirectory(moduleB)
```

```
#moduleA/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.14)
project(moduleA VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set (SOURCES fooA.cpp barA.cpp)
set (HEADERS fooA.h barA.h)
add_library(moduleA STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(moduleA PUBLIC moduleB)
```

The error is essentially the compiler not finding `moduleA` headers, when compiling `moduleA` source code, because the `moduleA` source files include headers in the same directory in an unusual (to me) way, `#include "moduleA/header"`.

Comment: `include_directories(..)` may do what you want.

Comment: ***this unusual header structure*** I think this is a quite common header structure.

Comment: @drescherjm I am used to not including the directory name in `#include` statements if the header files are in the same directory as the source file, so this is unusual to me. In which `CMakeLists.txt` should I add `include_directories(..)`?

Comment: I would add inside `lib/CMakeLists.txt` a `add_library(lib INTERFACE)` with `target_include_directoires(lib INTERFACE .)` and link with that library. But you could just `target_include_directories(moduleA PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Tried the second option, and it worked. Could you please explain what is the difference between the two options?

Comment: One adds a new interface library and the other adds include directory to moduleA library. Cmake is quite verbose, when you start reading function just as they are spelled. In the first I need link moduleA and moduleB with the interface library.